# Do IOC Orders Stay on the Order Book for Any Period of Time

Tags: market-microstructure, limit-order-book, exchange, order-execution

I'm confused on whether or not an IOC (Immediate Or Cancel) order will stay on the order book for any period of time.

For example, if I place an IOC buy limit order at \$1.00 and the ask price is $1.01, is this order immediately cancelled? If so, do IOC limit orders always have to be at or above the ask when buying, or at or below the bid when selling in order to get executed?

If they do go on the book, is there some set duration of time they remain active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will not stay and therefore your conclusion is correct.

The behaviour you describe can be achieved by setting a time in force on the order or manually canceling after some time.